# Why are some of my tree branches dead

Tags: identification, trees, plant-health, dead-branch

We recently moved into a new house with a garden and this tree in the middle. I don’t know the type of tree - we live in Australia so it could be a native tree or imported.

I noticed that the tree has many new leaves(nice green buds) but also lots of dead looking leaves on dead looking branches.

I was wondering if this is normal for the tree, if I should prune these dead branches or even if the branches are really dead. Also I don’t know what might be wrong with the tree if anything and what I can do to help it.

Any thoughts or advice welcome - even just starting with helping identifying the tree.

Pictures below of the tree. It’s healthy leaves and the dead looking branches.

[image: tree]
[image: healthyleaves]
[image: deadleaves]

Comment: Is there a tree surgeon/certified arborist in your area? If so, I recommend calling them. They'd be able to identify the tree and any problems there may be with it. Do NOT call a "tree guy" or someone whose jobs consists solely of cutting trees down or you'll just be told that it's dying and needs to be cut down.

Answer (score 1):

Very much looks like a *Liquidamber styraciflua*
with the five-lived leaves and bark pattern.

If you are in southern Australia, there may well be flower buds coming about now. Check weekly, and photograph them. Also look for seed cases.

It is still spring, wait a bit for leaves. Or cut the suspect branch, see if green inside. Also see colour of sap - gives the tree its name!

Below are photos I took today of one.
[image]
Flower bud mid Oct.

[image]

Spiky seed pod underneath.